# Authentication handshake between two independent apps

Tags: authentication, web-application, asymmetric, jwt, handshake

I need help on a solution for below scenario from a security perspective.

***Scenario:***

There are two independent web applications App1 and App2.
User will log in to App1 by performing authentication demanded by App1.
Once authenticated, the user will find a hyperlink to access App2.
On click of the hyperlink, App1 will pass the minimum parameters required for session creation (user-id) to App2.
User should be logged into App2 in a ’new tab’ on behalf of passed 'user-id’.

***Current approach:***

By means of asymmetric cryptography, App1 will have a key-pair.
App1 creates a JWT token (embedding ‘App2 user-id’)  as part of initial handshake with a JWT expiry and post it to App2.
App2 verifies the JWT signature of App1 and checks for the JWT expiry.
On success, App2 continues to create a session for the user in a 'new tab’.

***Problem***:

Although the JWT is sent over https, it's not opaque during transit.
While secrecy being an issue, what are the other security risks in the current approach?
What could be a better authentication handshake, as opposed to the aforementioned process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JWT can either be signed, encrypted or both. Please use the case of encrypted and signed for secrecy of the App2 user-id (and other details) transmitted via JWT.
Please refer [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-11.2) for more details.
It's recommended to sign and then encrypt but vice versa is also possible.